# ActionSelectionPopover - populate dynamically

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am trying to populate dynamically an ActionSelectionPopover... Does any one ever got it working?

this is the static way to get it work:

```js
ActionSelectionPopover {
    id: popMeUp
    data: bitrates
    delegate: ListItems.Standard {
        text: text
    }

    actions:  ActionList {
        id: myActions
        Action {
            text: "option 1"
            onTriggered: {
                popMeUp.hide()
                print(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the powerful method [Qt.createQmlObject()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) to populate dynamically the action list with the result of a JS function, like this:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.Popups 0.1

Rectangle {
    id: mainView
    width: units.gu(30) 
    height: units.gu(40)

    ActionSelectionPopover {
        id: actionSelectionPopover
    }


    Button {
        id: actionSelectionPopoverButton
        text: i18n.tr("action list")
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        width: units.gu(16)

        function my_actions(){
            var actions = []
            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
                var text = ['import Ubuntu.Components 0.1; Action {text: "', i.toString(), '";}'].join('')
                actions.push(Qt.createQmlObject(text, actionSelectionPopoverButton, "action"+i));
            }
            return actions;
        }

        onClicked: {
            actionSelectionPopover.actions = my_actions()
            actionSelectionPopover.caller = actionSelectionPopoverButton;
            actionSelectionPopover.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Even though this is not exactly what I need, indeed it was the help that I needed. I just need to adapt it. Thanks a lot, it will work ;)